# Change keyboard back to English in command line from Cyrillic

Tags: command-line, language-support, input-language, system-language

I switched to Russian keyboard via `loadkeys ru` command and now cannot switch back.

A directory and subsequent files I have are titled in Cyrillic characters and I am trying to get to them by a combination of commands in Latin characters and Cyrillic ones. So far I've been stuck on Cyrillic.

Does anyone know how to switch back if I have only Cyrillic characters available?

Answer (score 3):

I feel there must be a much more logical/sane solution compared to what I'm about to propose, such as running `sudo loadkeys us` from the graphical terminal whose layout is independent, or restarting the machine (as already suggested).

If none of those are an option, however, you could use the following pants-on-the-head technique:

1. Find the original line in shell history with the <kbd>↑</kbd> key. It should be `sudo loadkeys ru`. Alternatively, find any line that has `u` and `s` in it.
2. Remove all characters except for `us`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (Bash will complain that `command not found`.)
3. Now go back to your `loadkeys ru` line.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. In the Russian layout <kbd>/</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>.</kbd>. And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is mapped `yank-last-arg` in bash, which is the command that inserts the last argument from the previous command. In this case, it will be `us` that we've assembled in the previous step.
5. This should leave you `loadkeys us`. All it takes now is to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If it happens that there are no commands with both <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> in them, you could do steps 2 and 3 twice, and pick those characters from 2 different commands.

Answer (score 2):

The Russian keymap probably has a modifier key for Latin text.

Some likely suspects are the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key (Latin lock), the right Alt (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>) key, or possibly the combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> together.

If you could look at the keymap file (or run `dumpkeys`) then you'd know for sure. But it might be difficult to find information while your keyboard is stuck in an unfamiliar mapping!

### The keymap file

The comment at the top of `/usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty/ru.kmap.gz` in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) says:

> "Cyrillic" mode is toggled by Right_Ctrl key and shifted by AltGr key.

I hope your keyboard has a right-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key! If it doesn't, you'll need to hold down right-Alt (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>) while you switch.

Comment: This is **the** right approach! Unfortunately, not all keyboards have AltGr either. I think European and UK/AU/NZ keyboards have it, while for instance US and RU keyboards simply have two Alt keys by default (one of which can be remapped to AltGr nonetheless, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the standard(ish) shortcut that is `ctrl+space` ?

If, when installing a new keyboard you didn't suppress the English one, this shortcut should switch between one and the other.